# error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘' in static template

Tags: c++, templates, static

I am trying to defing a table of function pointers that can be searchable by string.
I defined the following template class but I have trouble with the static member.

The error I have is

```
     test.cpp:18: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion 
     before ‘Attribute’
```

Even If a add a constructor it doesn't work: do you know what's the reason the compiler is telling me that and what is missing from this simple piece of code?

```
     #include<iostream>
     #include<map>
     #include<boost/function.hpp>

     using namespace std;
     using namespace boost;

     template<class T>
     class Attribute {
     public:             
       typedef map<string, boost::function<void(T*,string) > > Params;
       static Params params_;
     };

     template<class T>
     T::Params Attribute<T>::params_;
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `typename` before `T::Params`.

```
template<class T>
class Attribute
{
public:
    typedef map<string, boost::function<void(T*,string) > > Params;
    static typename T::Params params_;
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
};

template<class T>
typename T::Params Attribute<T>::params_;
^^^^^^^^
```

---

Or...

```
template<class T>
class Attribute
{
public:
    typedef map<string,int > Params;
    static Params params_;
};

template<class T>
typename Attribute<T>::Params Attribute<T>::params_;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: It's the "or" side of your answer - otherwise there would be no point for OP to `typedef` his own `Params`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Probably you're right. I was not sure.

Comment: I completely forgot about it! Thanks a lot